# Write file on client system using applet

Tags: java, security, file-io, applet, next-generation-plugin

I want to write a file on client using applet. I have some it can write when we run the applet as separate from Java. But it can't write through browser by calling the applet function from javascript.

How can I write files on client system?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there are two (practical) ways to write files to the client file system from an applet.

1. A digitally signed, trusted applet.
2. A Plug-In 2 applet that uses the JNLP API services.

Comment: finall y i created the applet to write a file and signed the jar...i want to call that writing function from javascript...